# How exactly does the '0' ,located in the do-clause, work with the itoa function?

Tags: c

The itoa function is listed in the C Programming Language Book (K+R) as follows:

```
void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
 int i, sign;
 if ((sign = n) < 0) /* record sign */
 n = -n; /* make n positive */
 i = 0;
 do { /* generate digits in reverse order */
 s[i++] = n % 10 + '0'; /* get next digit */          ***THIS IS WHERE THE "+ '0'" OCCURS***
 } while ((n /= 10) > 0); /* delete it */
 if (sign < 0)
 s[i++] = '-';
 s[i] = '\0';
 reverse(s);
 }
```

When I take out the " + '0' " I get a "Segmentation Fault = 11" error which, please correct me if I'm wrong, occurs when you're going out of bounds. I'm trying to better understand what's going on here. Thank you

Comment: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Adding `'0'` to an integer will produce the character value for the digit corresponding to the integer (assuming the integer is in the range 0-9, and that the character values `'0'` through `'9'` are consecutive).  You could do the same thing with the alphabet, e.g. `5 + 'a'` should produce `'f'` if the alphabetic character codes are consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

`itoa()` converts a number to a string, so each digit has to be converted from a value in the range `0-9` to a character in the range `’0’-‘9’`. Because the characters happen to appear in order in ASCII, you can do that by adding the value of the digit to the value of the lowest character, `’0’`.

I’m not sure about the segmentation fault, but one problem you might run into without the `+’0’ is that your string will have a zero byte wherever a zero appears in the number you’re converting, making the string look shorter than it really is.

Comment: The C standard actually requires the numerical characters 0-9 to be in order, it's not simply a function of ASCII having it be so.

Answer (score 0):

The `'0'` is the base value of the numbers in the ASCII table. The ASCII character "0" has a decimal value of 48. In order to compute the correct ASCII character for the integers 0-9, you can add `'0' + n`, where `n` is the decimal value. To see this in action, replace `'0'` in the code with `48`. The resulting string will be the same.

This works because the `char` data type in C is just a small integer (a single byte) and the `'0'` is syntactic sugar for the `char` value 48.

Comment: Except when the code set is [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) — then `'0'` has the value 240.  That isn't a major problem for most people most of the time, but your answer implies that `'0'` must be equivalent to 48, which isn't accurate.

Comment: iirc the type of `char` literals is actually `int`

Answer (score 0):

The ascii char `'0'` code is `48` in decimal.
Whenever `n % 10` returns `0` (that will happen for any digit that is `0`), then you're actually injecting a null byte into s.

My guess is that the segmentation fault actually occurs within the call of `reverse(s)`.

Comment: `n % 10` returns `0-9`, adding `'0'` converts the numeric value to the ASCII character code for the digit. Not only for `0`, and adding `'0'` to `0` simply gives the ASCII character code for `'0'` and doesn't inject a null-byte.